# Send Batch email UI design in Angular

Tags: angular, user-interface

I want to create a UI design similar to sending batch email.
Is there any library in Angular which supports UI of Send Batch email like this :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. It's called tag input.

html :

```
   <div [formGroup]="form">
    <div class="editor-tag" (click)="focusTagInput()">
        <span class="tag-item" *ngFor="let tag of tags">{{tag}}
          <span class="remove-tag" (click)="removeTag(tag)">×</span>
        </span>
        <input placeholder="" #tagInput type="text" class="input-tag"
        (keyup)="onKeyUp($event)"  formControlName="tag">
      </div>
    </div>
```

css :

```
.editor-tag {
  cursor: text;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px #cccccc solid;

  & .tag-item {
    line-height: 20px;
    border-radius: 14px;
    height: 20px;
    font-size: 14px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: greenyellow;
    padding-left: 5px;

    .remove-tag {
      padding-right: 5px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  }

  & .tag-item:not(:first-child) {
    margin-left: 5px;
  }

  & input {
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 5px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
}
```

ts:

```
  @ViewChild('tagInput') tagInputRef: ElementRef;
  tags: string[] = ['html', 'Angular'];
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      tag: [undefined],
    });
  }

  focusTagInput(): void {
    this.tagInputRef.nativeElement.focus();
  }

  onKeyUp(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
    const inputValue: string = this.form.controls.tag.value;
    if (event.code === 'Backspace' && !inputValue) {
      this.removeTag();
      return;
    } else {
      if (event.code === 'Comma' || event.code === 'Space') {
        this.addTag(inputValue);
        this.form.controls.tag.setValue('');
      }
    }
  }

  addTag(tag: string): void {
    if (tag[tag.length - 1] === ',' || tag[tag.length - 1] === ' ') {
      tag = tag.slice(0, -1);
    }
    if (tag.length > 0 && !find(this.tags, tag)) {
      this.tags.push(tag);
    }
  }

  removeTag(tag?: string): void {
    if (!!tag) {
      pull(this.tags, tag);
    } else {
      this.tags.splice(-1);
    }
  }
```

Here's a working example of it - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tag-input-lpp8tx

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)